# Rolling equations from a non-inertial frame

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, rotational-dynamics, torque

In particle dynamics, I had used "pseudo forces" frequently, and i had come to the conclusion that pseudo forces ensure that analysis from a non inertial frame yield the same conclusion(s) as the ground/inertial frame.

I wanted to extend this thought further, to rigid body dynamics. Consider a disc of radius $R$ and moment of inertia about Center of mass to be $I_{com}$. We apply a force $F$ horizontally to the topmost point, and there is friction due to the ground. It is given that the object undergoes pure rolling instantly.

1. By writing Torque equation about the COM /IAOR, we end up with some relation between the quantities. (and by using $a-r\alpha=0$).
2. Now, consider a point $P$ at a distance $x$ vertically below the COM. And suppose, we have no knowledge of our previous analysis. We now write torque equation about this point.
   We will have to consider the torque of of the pseudo-force as well.

Can we know, end up with the exact same set of equations as we did earlier? I am particularly confused about the analogue of $(a-r\alpha=0)$ in the $P$-frame, since in $P$-frame, the bottom most point will obviously be moving.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting mathematical expressions.